# How can I call a function after the code in my other function is executed

Tags: javascript

How can I call a function that will simply display an alert box after the code in the following function is finished executing? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwjrw11f/1/) of the code in action, and now I want to be able to call the additional function below, "isComplete", after the code has completed in the runArray function.

```
function runArray(arr, fn, delay) {
var index = 0;
var cnt = 0;
var i = 0;

// Called once for each array element    
function next() {
    if (index >= arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    cnt = +arr[index];
    i = 0;
    loop();
}

// Represents a single iteration of what was previously a for loop
// Will either schedule the next iteration or move to the next element
function loop() {
    if (i < cnt) {
        fn(index, i++);
        setTimeout(loop, delay); // delay before next iteration
    }
    else {
        ++index;
        setTimeout(next, delay); // delay before moving to next element
    }
}

if (arr.length) {
    next();
}
}

function isComplete(){
alert('completed!');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you written this `runArray` function yourself?

Comment: yes, partly. It had been slightly modified by someone however I have tried jquery's $.when.done and making a callback function but was not successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an extra parameter `fnComplete` and pass it to the function. Then call it before the return statement:

```
function runArray(arr, fn, delay, fnComplete) {
    var index = 0;
    var cnt = 0;
    var i = 0;

    // Called once for each array element    
    function next() {
        if (index >= arr.length) {
            fnComplete();
            return;
        }
```

Calling the function:

```
runArray(theArray, theFunction, 100, isComplete);
```

Comment: a little confused, when calling the function, did you mean for the last parameter to be fnComplete, or isComplete?

Comment: oh wait, I see what you meant

Comment: 'fnComplete' is the name of the argument in the runArray function. 'isComplete' is the function you wish to pass to runArray.

Comment: You also will need to remove the `if (arr.length) {` condition for this to work.